# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package while running unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

[This is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y05Ab.png)

This is my unit test code

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
from ..services.user_service import UserService

class CreateUserTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    #Mock Data
    full_name = "John Doe"
    phone_number = "1234567890"
    email = "john.doe@example.com"
    
    def test_create_user_service_success(self, mock_user_class):
         # Create a mock for the User model
        mock_user = Mock()

        # Mock the save method of the User model
        mock_user.save.return_value = None

        # Replace the actual User class with the mock
        with patch('Models.models.User', mock_user):  # Corrected the patch path
            # Call the service method
            result = UserService.create_user(self.full_name, self.phone_number, self.email)

        # Assertions
        # assert result is not None  # Ensure the service method returns a result
        # assert mock_user.call_args == call(role_name="Admin", slug="admin", is_system_defined=True)
        assert mock_user.save.called_once()
```

The command I'm trying inside tests directory is - `python3 -m unittest test_user_service.py`

It's showing error

```
/api/v1/tests/test_user_service.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..tests.test_user_service import UserService
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

create_user function-

```
class UserService:
def create_user(email: str):
    try:
        user = User()
        user.email = email
        user.save()
        return user.to_json()
    except Exception as e:
        return None
```

Updated Code-

```
import sys
import os
project_dir =     
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 
"...."))
sys.path.append(project_dir)
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
from api.v1.services.user_service import UserService
from Models.models import User

class CreateUserTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    #Mock Data
    full_name = "John Doe"
    phone_number = "1234567890"
    email = "john.doe@example.com"

    @patch("Models.models.User")
    def test_create_user_service_success(self, mock_user_class):
        mock_user =  mock_user_class.return_value

        mock_user.save.return_value = mock_user
        result = None
        result = UserService.create_user(self.email)

        assert mock_user.save.called_once()
```

Comment: can you please show your file structure? import errors are not related to the code, but to the actual file that python is searching for

Comment: I've attached the file structure image along with the question.

Comment: A possible solution is to add in `test:user_service.py` the path ` /api/v1/tests` to the list `sys.path`. After that modify the wron import to `from services.user_service import UserService`.

Comment: @frankfalse I updated my code with proper imports(Added the code above)
This is my create_user function-
class UserService:
    def create_user(email: str):
        try:
            user = User()
            user.email = email
            user.save()
            return user.to_json()
        except Exception as e:
            return None

The problem now is that in the test file it is still trying to use 'user = User()' instead of mocking the mock data.

Comment: Please edit your question with the code that you have written in the comment.

Comment: @frankfalse I've added the code to the question. 'create_user function'

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your file `user_service.py` contained the import:

```
from Models.models import User
```

If this is true your file `test_user_service.py` must be changed as following:

```
import sys
import os
project_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../..")) # <--- here I have changed '....' to "../../.."
sys.path.append(project_dir)

import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

from api.v1.services.user_service import UserService
from Models.models import User

class CreateUserTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    # Mock Data
    full_name = "John Doe"
    phone_number = "1234567890"
    email = "john.doe@example.com"

    #@patch("Models.models.User")   # <--- Changed this patch() instruction
    @patch("api.v1.services.user_service.User")
    def test_create_user_service_success(self, mock_user_class):
        mock_user = mock_user_class.return_value

        #mock_user.save.return_value = mock_user    # <--- this instruction must be commented
        result = None
        result = UserService.create_user(self.email)

        #assert mock_user.save.called_once() # <--- this test IS NOT CORRECT
        mock_user.save.assert_called_once()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

### The `patch()` function

One of the errors is the patch():

```
@patch("Models.models.User")   # THIS patch() IS NOT CORRECT
```

it must be change to:

```
@patch("api.v1.services.user_service.User")
```

This because you have to substitute the object pointed by the name `User` present in the namespace of the module `user_service.py` which contains the class UserService and the method `create_user()`.
The method `create_user()` use the name `User` to instantiate an object of this class. This object must be substitute with `mock_user`.

### The error in the use of instruction `assert`

An other error is how to use the assert instruction.

To check if the method `UserService.create_user()` calls the method `save()` of the class `User` you have to use the following instruction:

```
mock_user.save.assert_called_once()
```

Your instruction `assert mock_user.save.called_once()` is always satisfied.

Comment: @Mahek Adhaduk This answer is suited for your question?